# Where is "HEAD" defined as not a valid branch name?

Tags: git

I'm looking at git docs, but nowhere does it say "HEAD" is an invalid branch name. Yet, trying to make a branch called "HEAD" gives me:

```
fatal: 'HEAD' is not a valid branch name.
```

If this is documented anywhere, I'm not seeing it. As far as the documentation is concerned, I should be able to do this? But why can't I?

Comment: This is akin to naming a variable `variable`. Don't do that. Want to shoot your foot? There are plenty of other very bad branch names which aren't restricted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name `HEAD` (in all capitals) is special and precious in Git.  If the special `HEAD` file, `.git/HEAD`, goes missing, Git stops believing that the repository is a repository.

[The `git check-ref-format` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) *should* note that `HEAD` is not a valid name here, but fails to do so.  (It does note that `@`, a synonym for `HEAD`, is reserved.)

Note that `head` (lowercase) *is* allowed as a branch name—but if you are on Windows or MacOS, don't use it!<sup>1</sup>  It will act weird, due to the resolution order as noted in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), where the file system will allow Git to open the special `HEAD` file under the name `head`.

---

Technically, this caveat applies anywhere you have a case-insensitive file system.  You can have one on Linux, and you can make case-sensitive file systems on MacOS.

Comment: Also, don't write `head` when you mean `HEAD`, even if you happen to have a case-insensitive file system, because it breaks it a variety of interesting ways.

Comment: @bk2204 I almost included that here, but it gets a little tricky to describe properly. :-)